# Invalid await in RequestPromise

Tags: typescript, request, request-promise

I've got a TSLint error which says "Invalid 'await' of a non-Promise value." for the following line:

```
const response: RequestResponse = <RequestResponse>await this.apiRequest(uri);
```

**Context code:**

```
private apiRequest: RequestAPI<request.RequestPromise, request.RequestPromiseOptions, RequiredUriUrl>;
this.apiRequest = request.defaults({
      baseUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
      method: 'GET',
      encoding: 'utf8'
    });
```

According to the Type definitions the return type for `this.apiRequest(uri)` is `request.RequestPromise`. `RequestPromise` again is defined like this in the @types/request-promise library:

```
interface RequestPromise extends request.Request, Promise<any> {
      promise(): Promise<any>;
}
```

Shouldn't it be possible to await the RequestPromise then since it just extends a Promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this does not work is that request-promise is using Bluebird as Promise library. Tslint is bleating because you are awaiting a Bluebird promise and not a native promise.

At the top of `@types/request-promise` you will find the Promise override

`import Promise = require('bluebird');`

In order to get rid of the tslint warning you can either use the request library using native promises (request-promise-native) or simply use `.then()` instead of `await` to wait for the resolved response.